# Javascript shorthand if-else and returning

Tags: javascript

Can the javascript shorthand for if-else return out of a function? If so how would this work.

eg. 
I have this:

```
if(boolean){
 return;
}
```

and I would like to write it as this:

```
(value)? return;
```

Chrome complains that return is unexpected. Is there anyway to write something like this so that it is valid?

Comment: It's not a shorthand for if-else. It's a completely different construct, and one which is not appropriate for this task.

Comment: Really sad that this doesn't work: `someVal && return;`. Console says `unexpected token return`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, you can't do that unless you return a value. For example if your function had to return a value you could have written:

```
return boolean ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

But you cannot stop the execution of the function by returning void using the conditional operator.

Answer (score 31):

If you intend to return from the function at this point in its execution *regardless* of whether the test evaluates true or false, you can use,

```
return (value) ? 1 : 2;
```

But if you merely wish to return early when a test evaluates true (for instance, as a sanity-check to prevent execution when parameters are invalid), the shortest you can make it is:

```
if (boolean) return;
```

Comment: Only the second actually behaves identically to the first example in the question. It certainly is shorter though - good illustration of how slavishly including braces and newlines can lead to a desire to shoot yourself in the foot!

Answer (score 20):

```
if(boolean) return;
```

Single line , readable , perfectly valid;

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but I want to add that there is a non-standard way to return out of a function in shorthand if-else, and that is performing Immediately Invoked Function Expression (**IIFE**):

```
function outOfFunction(boolean){

    return (boolean)?(()=>{return true;})():(()=>{return false;})();

}

console.log(outOfFunction(true));
console.log(outOfFunction(false));
```

And if we want to be out of the function or continue with other task:

```
    function shorthandExampleJustTrue(boolean){

        var someVar = "I'm out";        

        return (boolean)?(()=>{return true;})():(()=>{

          console.log("here my code ");

          console.log(someVar);

          return "anythig else";


        })();
    }

console.log(shorthandExampleJustTrue(true));
console.log(shorthandExampleJustTrue(false));
```

When we use arrow functions we are able to access to variables out of the immediate function context.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a `ternary operator`

which is this:

```
(bool) ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
```

Please note: you cannot omit the else portion of a ternary operator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: I don't think you understand what the "long" version of the code actually *did*...

Comment: No, I get it. But it appears as though he was attempting to use a ternary operator, and was trying to force it to behave in the way he envisioned it with his original "long" if statement. If he simply wanted to use an if statement sans-curly braces, he could have said so. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

The conditional "ternary operator" (`condition ?  expression to evaluate when true : expression to evaluate when false`) is often used for simple conditional variable assignment.

if you need :

```
if( x > 0) {
   a = 10;
}else{
   a = 30;
}
```

you can write:

```
a = (x>0)? 10 : 30;
```

You can think of it like a simple function, which takes 3 parameters (p1, p2, p3), if p1  is true it returns p2 and if p1 is false then it returns p3.

```
(p1)? p2 : p3;
```

And just like such a function, there's no way for it to cause the *parent* function to return based on the condition. It is *not* therefore a shorthand for if/else.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken you're talking about this right? a short-hand.

```
 return (if the value here is true then ->) && false
```

example:

```
const isGood = true && "yeah";
console.log(isGood) //yeah
```

Use this as your short hand if the value is true then it will return false; using the && operator is better